# sed match using `?` meta character does not work

Tags: regex, bash, sed

I have a bash variable, some file path (with spaces) and filename, e.g:

```
$ echo $tmp
/home/xyz/some/path/with spaces/AlbumArt_{random-number-sequence}_Large.jpg
```

When I attempt to identify the filename part with grep, e.g:

```
$ echo "$tmp" | egrep  'AlbumArt.*Large.jpe?g$'
/home/xyz/some/path/with spaces/**AlbumArt_{random-number-sequence}_Large.jpg**
```

The filename part appears to be identified correctly, but when I attempt to convert this to a sed substitution expression, e.g:

```
$ echo "$tmp" | sed 's@AlbumArt.*Large.jpe?g$@NewString@'
/home/xyz/some/path/with spaces/AlbumArt_{random-number-sequence}_Large.jpg
```

The expected substitution isn't happening. Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Try `\?` instead of `?` in the sed expression.

Comment: with egrep `?` would work, with sed, you'd need add `-E` command line option to enable ERE... see also https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/119905/why-does-my-regular-expression-work-in-x-but-not-in-y

Comment: Also, you should escape the `.` in front of `.jpe`.

Comment: The -E command line option fixes the problem, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In fact **egrep** is a variant of **grep -E**, allowing to 'activate' extended regular expression (you can see: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression#Standards).

Thus, you just need to use the same option with sed:

```
echo "$tmp" | sed -E 's@AlbumArt.*Large.jpe?g$@NewString@'
```

Answer (score 0):

As others have pointed out, you need to either backslash-escape the `?` or add the `-E` flag.

You can safeguard yourself against surprises by using `sed` to develop your regular expression. Instead of `grep`, use `sed`'s `p`rint command like this:

```bash
echo "$tmp" | sed -n '/AlbumArt.*Large.jpe?g/p'
```

Oops, no match! Let's try one of those ...

```bash
echo "$tmp" | sed -n '/AlbumArt.*Large\.jpe\?g/p'
echo "$tmp" | sed -nE '/AlbumArt.*Large\.jpe?g/p'
```

It has the added benefit that your command line can easily be turned into the `s`ubstitute command you were trying to come up with.